# Prestashop The object cannot be loaded (or found)

Tags: object, prestashop

Currently I'm developing custom loyalty program for my client.
I'm going to display the points in separate tab like this.
**Loyalty Program > (list of customers)  > (view their points) > (edit points)**

When I click a customer it will render list of customer's point but there is no problem with rendering but it displaying following error.

> **The object cannot be loaded (or found)**

Please help me to overcome from this error.

```
require_once (_PS_MODULE_DIR_.'\loyaltyprogram\classes\LoyaltyClass.php');
class AdminLoyaltyController extends AdminController
{

    public $module;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->table = 'loyaltyprogram';
        $this->className = 'LoyaltyClass';
        $this->module = 'loyaltyprogram';
        $this->lang = false;
        $this->bootstrap = true;
        $this->need_instance = 0;
        $this->context = Context::getContext();
        $this->fields_list = array(
            'id_customer' => array(
                'title' => $this->l('Id'),
                'width' => 100,
                'type' => 'text',
            ),
            'firstname' => array(
                'title' => $this->l('First Name'),
                'width' => 440,
                'type' => 'text'
            ),
            'lastname' => array(
                'title' => $this->l('Last Name'),
                'width' => 440,
                'type' => 'text'
            ),
            'email' => array(
                'title' => $this->l('Email'),
                'width' => 440,
                'type' => 'text'
            ),
            'point' => array(
                'title' => $this->l('Point'),
                'width' => 440,
                'type' => 'text'
            )
        );
        $this->identifier = 'id_customer';
        if (!Tools::getValue('id_customer'))
        {
            $this->_select = 'SUM(a.point) point, b.*';
            $this->_join = 'LEFT JOIN `'._DB_PREFIX_.'customer` b ON b.id_customer=a.id_customer';
        }
        $this->bulk_actions = array(
            'delete' => array(
                'text' => $this->l('Delete selected'),
                'icon' => 'icon-trash',
                'confirm' => $this->l('Delete selected items?')
            )
        );
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function renderList()
    {
        $this->addRowAction('view');
        $this->addRowAction('edit');
        $this->addRowAction('delete');

        return parent::renderList();
    }

    public function renderView()
    {
        if (($id = Tools::getValue('id_customer')))
        {

            // Action for list
            $this->addRowAction('edit');
            $this->addRowAction('delete');          


            $this->toolbar_title = 'Loyalty Program > ';
            $this->fields_list = array(
                'id_loyaltyprogram' => array(
                    'title' => $this->l('Id'),
                    'width' => 100,
                    'type' => 'text',
                ),
                'id_order' => array(
                    'title' => $this->l('Order Id'),
                    'width' => 100,
                    'type' => 'text'
                ),
                'point' => array(
                    'title' => $this->l('Point'),
                    'width' => 100,
                    'type' => 'text'
                ),
                'date' => array(
                    'title' => $this->l('Date'),
                    'width' => 200,
                    'type' => 'text'
                )
            );
            $this->identifier = 'id_loyaltyprogram';
            $this->_where = 'AND a.`id_customer` = '.(int)$id;
            return parent::renderList();
        }
    }

}
```

**LoyaltyClass.php**

```
class LoyaltyClass extends ObjectModel
{

/** @var string Name */
public $id_loyaltyprogram;

/** @var integer */
public $id_order;

/** @var integer */
public $point;
public $date;

/**
 * @see ObjectModel::$definition
 */
public static $definition = array(
    'table' => 'loyaltyprogram',
    'primary' => 'id_loyaltyprogram',
    'multilang' => false,
    'fields' => array(
        'id_loyaltyprogram' => array('type' => self::TYPE_INT, 'validate' => 'isInt'),
        'id_order' => array('type' => self::TYPE_INT, 'validate' => 'isInt', 'required' => true),
        'id_customer' => array('type' => self::TYPE_INT, 'validate' => 'isInt', 'required' => true),
        'point' => array('type' => self::TYPE_FLOAT, 'validate' => 'isUnsignedFloat', 'required' => true),
        'date' => array('type' => self::TYPE_STRING, 'validate' => 'isCleanHtml', 'required' => true),
    ),
);

public static function loadLoyaltyProgram()
{
    $result = Db::getInstance()->getRow('
        SELECT *
        FROM `' . _DB_PREFIX_ . 'loyaltyprogram` order_qty
        '
    );
    return new LoyaltyClass($result['id_loyaltyprogram']);
}

}
```

Comment: How is the class file named and where it is located?

Comment: Class file named as loyaltyclass.php and its is located in my module class folder

Answer (score 0):

1. The following code is not required at renderView()

   $this->table = 'loyaltyprogram';
   $this->className = 'LoyaltyClass';
   $this->module = 'loyaltyprogram';
2. You need to include the class file like:

   require_once(dirname(**FILE**).'/../../classes/LoyaltyClass.php');
3. Instead of making a new instance of LoyaltyClas you need to call loadObject() method, because it sets $this->object like:

   if (!($obj = $this->loadObject(true)))
       return;
4. If you will not use $obj within renderList() you don't have to load it.

Comment: Hi, as you said I include my class in my loyalty controller but still I facing the error. Please check the modified code and class above.